# running vim on windows leaves unwritable swap files behind

Tags: windows, vim, swap

I am running Cygwin on windows. Several times now I've had a swap file left behind from vim after a crash, but it can't be recovered or deleted. "ls -l" shows this:
-rw-r-----  1 Unknown+User Unknown+Group  12288 Feb 26 15:27 .pl.pl.swp

I'm not allowed to be an admin on my box, so I can't delete it. I'm not the owner so I cant' delete it either - it has unknown ownership.

Any ideas on how I can delete it (without pulling in a machine admin each time)? Can I have vim put its swapfiles in some other folder so at least they won't clutter up my working dir (I need the right .vimrc settings for running on windows)?

Comment: If one of your processes created the file, you're the owner.  Cygwin is confused or is lying to you.  You might not be able to delete the file via Cygwin, but Windows will allow you to do so, although you may need to reset the permissions first.

Comment: I am not able to delete the files with windows explorer, or in cmd window, and I can't change the permissions. It really is not owned by me.

Comment: What part of the settings for moving the swap files are giving you trouble? The same 'directory' option is used on every system.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Bizarrely, Windows [does allow giving files away](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404240.aspx), at least in some releases.  I imagine Vim has somehow contrived to do this, perhaps via Cygwin emulating the setuid bit or... something.

Comment: @Kevin: you can only assign ownership with administrative privileges.  That article is mistaken about being able to do it if you are the current owner.

Comment: @Harry: That would certainly make sense, but... cite?  TechNet *is* a Microsoft publication.

Comment: @Kevin: I'll see if I can turn anything up, but basically it's just common knowledge - that's the way it's always worked.  In particular, the article claims to be about Windows 7, and if you actually try it on a Windows 7 system you'll find that the "Edit" button is UAC protected - you have to provide admin privileges to continue.

Comment: @Kevin, here it is: [SetNamedSecurityInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  "If the caller does not have the SeRestorePrivilege constant (see Privilege Constants), this SID must be contained in the caller's token, and must have the SE_GROUP_OWNER permission enabled."

Comment: (The only case I know of where SE_GROUP_OWNER is enabled is the Administrators group.  Whether *that* is documented anywhere I have no idea.)

Comment: Can I point vim swap files to another folder?

Answer (score 4):

You can disable swapfiles entirely with `set noswapfile` or, if you still want that feature but not the clutter, tell Vim to put those files in a dedicated location:

```
set directory=c:\\tmp
```

Note that you'll still have to delete existing swapfiles manually.

Read the following help sections for more information:

```
:help 'swapfile'
:help swap-file
:help 'directory'
```

Comment: Looks like rebooting allows them to go away. I'll direct the swap files to another folder, then I won't have to reboot every time vim crashes. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

in your case, windows platform,

option 1: using cmd console, go to the folder which contains the swp files

```
del /A:H *.swp
```

option 2: using cygwin console, go to the folder samely

```
find . -type f -name "*.sw[klmnop]" -delete
```